# Cube - Plane cut

Tags: geometry

I have a unit cube and plane, given by its normal vector and variable `d`. How can I found `d` value, so plane-cube  intersection produce maximal number of vertices (6, 5 or 4) for given plane normal ?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

- Intersection of two planes is at least a line (and sometimes a plane).
- To obtain a point you need to intersect your plane with some *lines* (or points).
- Perform an orthogonal projection of every edge of the cube onto your normal vector and see what happens (possibly draw a picture).
- Note that there are many special cases...

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$